# How can I use an if statement in a $.jQuery ajax post's success:?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got an webapp and a serverside app, when the serverside app saved the webapp's POST successfully it responds with a 'saved' otherwise it returns a 'error', how can I create an `IF` statement to check the response?

```
function send(family){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://sistema.agrosys.com.br/webpro/webadm/wcgarvore',
            data: family,
            success: function(data, textStatus ){
               console.log('DONE: Request has been successfully sent');
               if(data === 'error'){ //how can I do it
                   alert("ERR:\n\ncouldn't save");
               }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert('Envio Falhou\n\nERR: '+errorThrown);
            }
      });
}
```

Comment: when there is an error there will be no call to `success` function.

Comment: is it a custom error in success and what is your response type ?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan that error is for Posting, not for what happens in the server

Comment: the`data['error'] == 'error'` would have to come from the response of the url assuming the post is successful but the saving was not

Comment: @n01ze simple text/string

Comment: it wud be nice if u use json and send some success flags , so that you can catch in success callback and show accordingly

Comment: @n01ze isn't there a way to put an `IF` statement?

Comment: Yep , what are you doing('IF') in success is correct

Comment: @n01ze but it's not working? (or you're being sarcastic?! :D )

Comment: @Calne why on the holy Earth I will ? You are using 'IF' correctly but on what kinda response I dont know

Comment: Your code looks right. May be you'll have better luck trying this `if($.trim(data) === 'error')`. Could be a whitespace issue.

Comment: @Calne you can loosly check in if condition by "==" only using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and trim the return string **`if($.trim(data) === 'error')`**. It might be a white space issue. You can be sure if you check in the console and see what is being returned. Trim the return and then compare.

Comment: worked, yeah trimming the data was I good idea, even though both were the same length no spaces, what could it have been? +1

Comment: @Calne In server processing white spaces are usually added. Even though the string looked like same we are not seeing the white spaces. \n and \r are there in the return.

Comment: ohh, that's sneaky, I'd take a year to notice that, thanks Rejith :)

Comment: and it's not the first time you helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

If the server responds with the proper error message then it will be received in success handler.

so, success handler you will be receiving data as an object or string.

now, in this case you are expecting it to be a string 'error' and not checking for object, it might be data.status or data.textstatus .

so add console.log(data) before the if condition and check.

```
console.log(data);
if(data.status == 'error'){}
```

if data is in object check check for the corresponding condition.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of that console?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example (tested with PHP 5.5.9 and Firefox 39).

ajaxtest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sendAjax').click(function () {
                send($('input[name="param"]').val());
            });
        });
        function send(test_data){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajaxtest.php',
                data: { msg: test_data },
                success: function(data, textStatus ){
                    console.log('DONE: Request has been successfully sent');
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data === 'error'){
                        $('#response').text('error');
                        $('input[name="param"]').val('get_success');
                    } else {
                        $('#response').text('success');
                        $('input[name="param"]').val('get_error');
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('Envio Falhou\n\nERR: '+errorThrown);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="sendAjax">Send Ajax</button>
<div id="response"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="get_success" />
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxtest.php

```
<?php
if ($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'get_error') {
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

Hope this helps.